# mongorestore from multiple dumps

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I have a mongo-database where existing entries never change but new entries are added every day. I have ~1000 dumps, each is the new data that was added on the corresponding day.

I.e. I have the following files:

```
/dump1/mydatabase/mycollection1.bson
/dump1/mydatabase/mycollection1.metadata.json
/dump1/mydatabase/mycollection2.bson
/dump1/mydatabase/mycollection2.metadata.json
...
/dump2/mydatabase/mycollection1.bson
/dump2/mydatabase/mycollection1.metadata.json
/dump2/mydatabase/mycollection2.bson
/dump2/mydatabase/mycollection2.metadata.json
...
...
...
/dump1000/mydatabase/mycollection1.bson
/dump1000/mydatabase/mycollection1.metadata.json
/dump1000/mydatabase/mycollection2.bson
/dump1000/mydatabase/mycollection2.metadata.json
```

I would like to restore "mydatabase" containing all the collections. The content in each of the collections should be appended to the existing collections instead of overwriting them.

When I run

```
mongorestore /dump1
mongorestore /dump2
...
```

will this append my data to the existing collections or overwrite them?

Comment: Relevant keywords : how to restore several dumps from `mongodump` with `query` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below the wordings from MongoDB official documentation ([Insert Only](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#insert-only)) :

> mongorestore can create a new database or add data to an existing database. However, mongorestore performs inserts only and does not perform updates. **That is, if restoring documents to an existing database and collection and existing documents have the same value _id field as the to-be-restored documents, mongorestore will not overwrite those documents.**

To answer your question, no, the documents won't be overwritten.